# Error when trying to spin spark in standalone mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have downloaded spark from "https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html"

But can't get it to run, get the following error when i try to start it in standalone mode as mentioned here "https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html". Please advice

```
adminisatorsmbp:spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 amit$ ./sbin/start-master.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /Users/amit/Documents/Analytics/kaggle/Bosch/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-adminisatorsmbp.out
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
    ... 10 more
full log in /Users/amit/Documents/Analytics/kaggle/Bosch/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-adminisatorsmbp.out
adminisatorsmbp:spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 amit$
```

Here are the complete logs

```
Spark Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -cp /Users/amit/Documents/Analytics/kaggle/Bosch/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/Users/amit/Documents/Analytics/kaggle/Bosch/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host adminisatorsmbp --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/10/24 17:40:26 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 35702@localhost
16/10/24 17:40:26 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/10/24 17:40:26 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/10/24 17:40:26 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: adminisatorsmbp: adminisatorsmbp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:916)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.MasterArguments.<init>(MasterArguments.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.main(Master.scala:1010)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.main(Master.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: adminisatorsmbp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
    ... 10 more
```

[image]

Comment: are you trying to make this run in a cluster?

Comment: No standalone only

Comment: are you just using a single computer for that? if so, you can start standalone using `./bin/spark-shell` without doing any modifications from the download.

Comment: Yes single computer(mac)

Comment: Getting errors--16/10/24 19:25:24 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: adminisatorsmbp: adminisatorsmbp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
 at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:866)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:859)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:859)

Comment: could you comment out the changes you made in `/etc/hosts`? also, `./bin/spark-shell` will fire up spark using scala. To start pyspark, you need to type `./bin/pyspark` instead.

Comment: BTW i don't have any hadoop installation on my mac, Is that something that can cause it to not work?

Comment: no. not necessarily. did you make any changes related to hadoop?

Comment: no no changes related to hadoop

Comment: Still the same error when i run ./bin/pyspark ---> 16/10/24 19:39:45 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: adminisatorsmbp: adminisatorsmbp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
 at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)

Comment: that's certainly strange. what version of java and scala do you have?

Comment: adminisatorsmbp:~ amit$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: i am not sure if i have scala, how can i check that

Comment: ok i have just install scala and now when i do ./bin/pyspark in terminal i can see sparksession running successfully.

Comment: In this article "https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html" it says i need to do this "./sbin/start-master.sh" but its not running for me

Comment: try to update your java version as well as scala. java should be 1.8 and scala should be 2.11. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

In conf folder you need to rename spark-env.sh.template as spark-env.sh and also slaves.template as slaves.
And try above steps it and make sure then in/etc/hosts you have correct mapping of ip and host name.

Comment: Thanks sandeep, i am new to mac world. How/where to check for etc/hosts? I mean what are the commands

Comment: This is how it looks when i open /etc/hosts                                                     ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost